# How to add Nagios custom states

Tags: linux, monitoring, centos6, nagios, server-monitoring

I am Using Nagios XI. Currently My Nagios showing three states of alerts: CRITICAL, WARNING and OK.
I want to add another custom hard state FATAL for some extreme issues like server or any of my component(Java jar component) is down. Currently we are getting the DOWN message when the Host is Down.  If the component is down I am getting "URL Status is CRITICAL" But I want "URL Status is FATAL". Is that possible to add a custom State in Nagios? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The states are built in (along with a fouth state, UNKNOWN, which is generally used if the plugin fails for reasons that probably belong to the plugin itself, not the object being monitored).

The states are intended to mean "requires action immediately (CRITICAL)" and "will probably require action soon (WARNING)". There's nothing left which would make your FATAL state different from CRITICAL, so i suggest you use that.

If you want to pass additional information to operators, you can always do that in the text the plugin provides.

(As Nagios is open source, you could probably modify the source code to allow another state. But this would be a huge task to implement properly, make your installation incompatible with the rest of the world, no plugins except yours would support it, and you'd have to re-apply and rewrite your patches with every new version of Nagios, so i'd strongly recommend against it).

Answer (score 0):

You can't add states. But if you only want to make your alerts stand out more clearly, you can modify the nagios-Stylesheets in /etc/nagios3/stylesheets/ or add custom javascript in /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/ssi/<nagiospage>-header.ssi and highlight the respective messages from there.